# Importance of using JSON objects compared to large strings of data?

Tags: java, xml, json, object

I have recently started using JSON and was wondering if I am missing any other important reasons as to why I would use a JSON object instead of just returning a large string of data.

Here is what I have found so far:
A JSON object is a lot faster to process, easier to handle and parse. A JSON object is easier for a human to read compared to a big string of data output. JSON objects can be mapped easier and works well with object oriented systems.

Comment: When you say, "large string of data" - are you talking about a specific format?  xml?  JSON strings can also be quite large.

Comment: I was comparing to XML.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  The question should be clear all by itself, without the comments.  Can you please edit the question to include the information you put in that comment, as well as anything else that would make it more clear?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JSON *is* **just a [large] string of data**.

The difference from a one-off/custom "blob'o'test" encoding is that **JSON is a [*well-defined format*](http://json.org)** that supports common ADTs (Arrays, Maps) and is a useful interchange format. Also, one doesn't work with JSON (which is *just text*) directly; one *works* with the object-graphs that are serialized to/from JSON - e.g. once you call `JSON.parse(jsonText)` you're dealing with *regular objects*.

While XML is another well-defined format, JSON has a better 1-1 mapping with simple object-graphs. This easier mapping eliminates the need for a specific DOM wrapper or other specialized access - who wants to deal with an object model when one can treat an object-graph as first-class data?<sup>1</sup>

The fact that JSON (which is *just text*) also looks like normal JavaScript Object Literal Notation (and excluding some odd Unicode issues, is a subset) makes human consumption relatively easy and has greatly helped the adoption.

Refer to the following questions for additional insight on "What?" and "Why?"

- [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)
- [What is the exact use of JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369328/what-is-the-exact-use-of-json)
- [Why use JSON instead a normal html output with AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425728/why-use-json-instead-a-normal-html-output-with-ajax)
- [Why is it a bad practice to return generated HTML instead of JSON? Or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284381/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-return-generated-html-instead-of-json-or-is-it)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json
- [Why is Everyone Choosing JSON Over XML for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743532/why-is-everyone-choosing-json-over-xml-for-jquery)

---

<sup>1</sup> XML is *much more* than a simple markup format, but comparing XML to JSON in any more detail is outside the scope of the question.